# natural language example to show difference between first order logic propositions

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

while discussing some problem in formal logic i came across two different formulas:
$ \lnot \exists y (P(y) \land Q)$ and $ (\lnot \exists y P(y))\land Q$

now, these 2 are obviously not equivalent, as the first one is trivially true when Q is false, while the second one is false when Q is false.

i tried to think of an example in natural language that highlights their difference, but could not come up with one.

any ideas how to express these 2 different concepts in ordinary language?

Comment: Any choice of a false ordinary language sentence for $Q$, and any formula whatsoever for $P$, will do the job. Say, take $P(y)$ = "$y$ is a duck" and $Q$ = "the earth is flat."

Comment: It's difficult to provide examples because basically nobody uses the first construction in natural language - it's stilted, weird, at best a logician's or linguist's joke. "I know a guy who's 7'1" and the Earth is flat": it's not clear what the scope is of "guy who". I don't think English makes it easy to vacuously quantify. You can't say *"I know a guy who the Earth is flat and is 7'1"" grammatically, you'd have to say something prolix like "I know a guy who's such that the Earth is flat and he's 7'".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a contrivance:

1. $ \lnot \exists y \:(P(y) \land Q)$

   There is no deer that is herbivorous, which is to say,
   animal-eating. (TRUE)

   (The given property is is incoherent as it contradicts an accepted definition.)
2. $ \lnot \exists y P(y)\land Q$

   There is no deer that is herbivorous, and herbivorous means
   animal-eating. (FALSE)

   (The second conjunct is analytically false.)

Comment: i accepted your answer, as it's the closest thing i found to a natural language example. as one of the commenters mentioned above, English isn't really interested about empty quantifications :)